Last value in precision_recall_curve for precision is 1 when it shouldn't be
I am trying to use the precision_recall_curve in sklearn. However, I don't understand the output it is giving me and I think it looks wrong.
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])
pred = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
precision, recall, thresholds = metrics.precision_recall_curve(y, pred, pos_label=1)

The outputted value of precision and recall here are:
precision: array([0.25, 0.33333333, 0.5, 0., 1.])
recall: array([1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])

But for the highest threshold we aren't predicting any samples in the 1 class. I feel like this is misleading if you were to plot it on a graph, particularly when comparing different models to each other. I would instead prefer to see:
precision: array([0.25, 0.33333333, 0.5, 0.])
recall: array([1., 1., 1., 0.])

Any help here? Can I just always remove the last point if this is the behaviour I would prefer?

Good catch and point.
The precision being 1 when recall is 0 for the final threshold of 0.4 in your case is an edge case often added in precision-recall curve implementations to complete the curve graphically.
It represents a scenario where no positives are predicted, hence no false positives, leading to a theoretical precision of 1.
Most libraries implement this edge case in the same way for the reason explained in the above sentence.

Does adding this make much sense when calculating things like the area under the precision recall curve? I wonder if it can make more sense in this case to not include this last value.
